# How to scrape all google images results for any search and download the html pages containing those returned results using scrapy and selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I am working on a web application project that will allow the user to get image search results from keywords. For this, I would like to send the user's search query to google images and get the search results webpage to display to the user on my site. However, I can't create a file automatically in my project where the content of the results html page will be written in scrapy. Having learned after research that scrapy does not support the basic json format, I was advised to use Selenium and Scrapy to perform this type of task with files containing json. So I watched  [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2LwrUu9yTAo) and I read this scrapy documentation [page](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html). Here is my code :

```
from requests import options

import scrapy
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome , ChromeOptions

class ImageSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name ="imageSearch"

    def start_requests(self):
        settings = get_project_settings()
        driver_path = settings.get()
        options = ChromeOptions()
        options.headless = True
        driver = Chrome(executable_path= driver_path , options = options)
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=money&sxsrf=ALiCzsY8zansk7q3trz5BEHZr-NeKtDHJQ:1652478338282&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjeu-jCud33AhUTgs4BHRBWCHMQ_AUoAXoECAIQAw")
        xpath = '//*'  #here is the modification 
        link_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)  #here is the modification 
        
        
        for link_el in link_elements :
            href = link_el.get_attribute('href')
            yield scrapy.Request(href)
            driver.quit()
            
    def parse(self, response):
        filename = f'imageSearch.html'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
            self.log(f'Saved file {filename}')
```

Here is my settings.py :

```
BOT_NAME = 'searchEngine'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['searchEngine.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'searchEngine.spiders'
CHROME_DRIVER_PATH = "C:\Windows"

#scrapeOps
## Add Your ScrapeOps API key
SCRAPEOPS_API_KEY = 'cc7988ca-72cc-4456-86ec-ed8c6e5fbdaf'

## Add In The ScrapeOps Extension
EXTENSIONS = {
 'scrapeops_scrapy.extension.ScrapeOpsMonitor': 500, 
}

## Update The Download Middlewares
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = { 
'scrapeops_scrapy.middleware.retry.RetryMiddleware': 550, 
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware': None, 
}
#scrapeOps
```

Unfortunately my program does not work as hoped because it does not create a file containing the html code of the page yet I have no problem, according to the console line scrappy started fine except I get the following errors:

- TypeError: BaseSettings.get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'

'log_count/DEBUG': 5,

'log_count/ERROR': 1,

'log_count/INFO': 10,

*

.I am beginner in webscrapping with selenium and scrapy and I don't really don't know what my mistakes are. Thank you, I look forward to your responses.

Comment: You have `link_elements = driver.find_elements` but you should put something in parenthesis, such as `link_elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[etc...]")`

Comment: As I said, I want to get the whole page so all the html elements, let's say I thought that by not specifying an element, the spider would have been forced to give me the whole page. And I'm not sure which XPATH or CSS query should I use to get the whole page.

Comment: And I don't think that explains why my program doesn't create an html file because even if there was an error I believe it should have created an empty file for me unless even my request to create an html file is false.

Comment: `find_elements` is a method, so to use it you HAVE TO put something between parenthesis, run `help(driver.find_elements)` if you don't believe me. With `link_elements = driver.find_elements` you are just calling the method with another name, in fact if you run `help(link_elements)` it prints the same message as before. As a consequence if you run `for link_el in link_elements:` you get the error `'method' object is not iterable` because `link_elements` it is not a list but a method. If you want the list of all the elements of a page, then do `driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*')`

Comment: Thanks for the fix at find_elements, I modified my code at that level but I still get the same errors except debug error 1 became debug error 5 and I have another error at About a missing parameter that I really don't understand, I'm not going to lie to you about that. I edited my question in which I give more details.